# javers MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR

Tags: java, javers

I did a refactoring and now my class B is not an Entity anymore but a Value.

If I try viewing the diff of an already audited Entity A, that contains a list of B's I am getting this exception: JaversException MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'class B' is mapped to ValueType, expected EntityType

Is there a recommended way how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, looks like there is no workaround other than manually deleting snapshots of previous Entity.
I have created the issue for this case https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/753